# Android EditText was not completely visible when keyboard appears

Tags: android, android-layout, android-edittext

My EditText was not completely visible when the keyboard appears, it was visible till focus but is there any possibility to view complete EditText.

[image]

Layout

```
<ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/scrollvew_direct"
        android:isScrollContainer="true"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <EditText
         android:id="@+id/edt_employers_name"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:inputType="text"
            android:maxLength="100"
            android:hint="@string/dir_deposit_6"
            android:textSize="@dimen/edittextsize_sub"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:textColor="@color/main_header"
            android:textColorHint="@color/hint_color_light"
            android:background="@drawable/edittext_style"/>
     </ScrollView>
```

In mainfest

```
<activity
android:name=".activityname"
android:screenOrientation="portrait"
android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"
android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light.NoActionBar"/>
```

please guide me for proper solution.

Comment: try android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"

Comment: if I use android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan",the keyboard overlays edit text.(i.e., the edit text was not moving up utill i scroll)

Comment: can u post full xml file?

Comment: this is my xml https://www.dropbox.com/s/a7tawdzq2wwkt12/keyboard.xml.xml?dl=0

Comment: can u post edittext_style

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/s/tdvzm3vmdh7vs3q/edittext_style.xml?dl=0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In you activity tag of the manifest , add this property

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"
```

**Edited** :
 Edittext height is not fully matched to the background drawable

make edittext  as

```
android:layout_height="match_parent" or
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
```

and check it for me it is working

Comment: if I use android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan",the keyboard overlays edit text.(i.e., the edit text was not moving up utill i scroll).

Comment: it was working thank you,and also please edit adjustPan to adjustResize

Answer (score 1):

In you activity tag of the manifest , add this property

`android:windowSoftInputMode="stateAlwaysHidden|adjustResize"`